# How to lock a staple gun?

Tags: tools, hand-tools

I have recently purchased a staple gun ([this model](https://www.stanleytools.co.uk/products/detail/Products/HAND+TOOLS/Manual+fastening+tools/Staple+guns+_+tackers/Staple+guns/STANLEY%C2%AE+FATMAX%C2%AE+TR75+LightDuty+fwdslash+HeavyDuty+fwdslashCablefwdslashBrads+CC), in case that matters, but I guess all of them work more or less the same way?)

I don't understand how to lock it.
The instructions say this:

1. push the handle down
2. pull it outwards

[image: lock steps]

First of all, I don't understand one thing: am I supposed to remove the staples before locking the staple gun (or always shoot one staple)? Or is there a point where I can push down just enough for not yet firing, but still be able to lock?

Also, I tried to push down and pull the handle, as described (without staples), but somehow it always "jumps back" and unlocks itself. I cannot find the point where it would stay fixed.

So is there a trick to this, that I'm missing?

Comment: All I can suggest, as I don’t have that model, is that you are not following the instructions correctly or the mechanism is now broken. If all you want to do is stop kids playing, then lock it in a cupboard.

Comment: No kids here, I just want to understand how it works :)

Comment: The mechanism is a spring loaded release. Although I have never locked a staple gun if the handle is not allowed to raise up it cannot be fired again. If you want to be sure it cannot be used remove the staples. Reloading and firing a staple gun is much harder than most firearms infact much harder than any I own.

Comment: I've never had a (normal, mechanical/spring, not power-assisted/pneumatic) staple gun fire unintentionally, so this just seems silly.

Comment: Interesting  - that model doesn't appear to be available in the USA.   Wonder why

Answer (score 3):

I have a few different staple guns - I don't think any have that handle lock.  One has a metal loop that hooks up to hold the hand down.  I think this is more to keep it in a smaller shape then prevent it from being used.

It wouldn't make sense to have to remove the staples just to lock the handle.

From the image I'd just pull the handle down to what it is level with the rest of the stapler (not fully engaged such that a staple is fired) and then pull away from the nose as indicated.  It is probably just a matter of playing with it until you get the handle into the correct position such that is can move away from the nose and lock.  I have pex crimpers that have a similar feature to open the jaws and it took a while to figure those out.